# Skipping vector iterations based on index equality

Tags: c++, vector

Let's say I have three vectors.

```
#include <vector>
vector<long> Alpha;
vector<long> Beta;
vector<long> Gamma;
```

And let's assume I've filled them up with numbers, and that we know they're all the same length. (and we know that length ahead of time - let's say it's 3.)

What I want to have at the end is the minimum of all sums `Alpha[i] + Beta[j] + Gamma[k]` such that `i`, `j`, and `k` are all unequal to each other.

The naive approach would look something like this:

```
#include <climits>

long min = LONG_MAX;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k < 3; k++) {

            if (i != j && i != k && j != k) {
                long sum = Alpha[i] + Beta[j] + Gamma[k];
                if (sum < min)
                     min = sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Frankly, that code doesn't feel right. Is there a faster and/or more elegant way - one that skips the redundant iterations?

Comment: FWIW, consider inverting the `if` and using a `continue` instead.

Comment: Theoretically, you could skip redundant iterations, but the increase in code size would not be worth it. It's unlikely to run faster, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computational complexity of your algorithm is an `O(N^3)`. You can save a very small bit by using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if ( i == j )
           continue;

        long sum1 = Alpha[i] + Beta[j];
        for (int k=0; k < 3; k++) {    
            if (i != k && j != k) {
                long sum2 = sum1 + Gamma[k];
                if (sum2 < min)
                     min = sum2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the complexity of the algorithm is still `O(N^3)`.

Without the `if ( i == j )` check, the innermost loop will be executed `N^2` times. With that check, you will be able to avoid the innermost loop `N` times. It will be executed `N(N-1)` times. The check is almost not worth it .

Comment: I'm feel like a typical optimizer would break `sum` apart just as you did. I wonder if it would do the same with the `i == j` condition, though?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, if you are able to understand the assembly code generated by your compiler, it might be worth formulating an answer using the assembly code.

Comment: The complexity is O(1) because the upper bounds are constant. As this does not scale, we just need to optimize the constant here.

Answer (score 1):

If you can temporarily modify the input vectors, you can swap the used values with the end of the vectors, and just iterate over the start of the vectors:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    std::swap(Beta[i],Beta[size-1]);     // swap the used index with the last index
    std::swap(Gamma[i],Gamma[size-1]);
    for (int j = 0; j < size-1; j++) {     // don't try the last index
        std::swap(Gamma[j],Gamma[size-2]); // swap j with the 2nd-to-last index
        for (int k=0; k < size-2; k++) {   // don't try the 2 last indices
            long sum = Alpha[i] + Beta[j] + Gamma[k];
            if (sum < min) {
                min = sum;
            }
        }
        std::swap(Gamma[j],Gamma[size-2]); // restore values
    }
    std::swap(Beta[i],Beta[size-1]);       // restore values
    std::swap(Gamma[i],Gamma[size-1]);
}
```